# Spring Data Cassandra codec not found for requested operation set<varchar> <-> java.util.Set

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

My entity has a field

```
@Column("authorizations")
@Builder.Default
private Map<String, Set<String>> authorizations = new HashMap<>();
```

When I query for that object via Spring Data repository I'm getting an exception

> CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation:
>   [set <-> java.util.Set]

Writes work just fine though. I can't believe this is not supported out of the box.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE resource_authorization_rules(
  resource text,
  region text,
  authorizations map<text, frozen<set<text>>>,
  PRIMARY KEY (resource, region)
);
```

Probably something with type erasure. How to tackle this with least effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the the Spring Data Casasndra. There is a [JIRA for improving support of frozen collections](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-465).  And it looks like that it could be worked around with custom row mapper as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199198/mapping-cassandra-listfrozenlistint-field-to-java-in-spring-data-cassandra?answertab=active#tab-top).

P.S. The DataStax Java Driver has [corresponding annotations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/object_mapper/creating/#mapping-collections) in their object mapper.