# Spring Data & Cassandra CQL, can we create table that have a List of Map, then query it?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

Im asking for the possibility to create a table in cassandra that contains a List of Map! like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agence(
id timeuuid,
code text,
libelle text,   
adresse set<frozen<map<text,text>>>,
conseillers  set<frozen<map<text,text>>>,
compagnie_id timeuuid,
```

...

In spring Data I have this query:

```
findAll()
```

then I got this error:

```
Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM agence;]; Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, varchar> <-> java.util.Map]
```

I dont know if there is a bad configuration or bad use of cassandra!!

Anyone has suggestion please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data Cassandra codec not found for requested operation set<varchar> <-> java.util.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541002/spring-data-cassandra-codec-not-found-for-requested-operation-setvarchar-j)

Comment: Why you don't use Object Mapper from DataStax driver? And `findAll` is really anti-patern for Cassandra. You should access data by key...

Comment: the findAll is just to test the request... however access data by key?

Comment: you need to have at least partition key in the `where` condition, or part or full primary key...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get a solution:

```
    /** The conseillers. */
@Column(value = "conseillers")
@Frozen
@FrozenKey
@FrozenValue
private Set<Map<String, String>> conseillers;
```

Like this we can map map <-> java.util.Map

```
    for(Row row : cassandraOperations.select("SELECT conseillers FROM agence", Row.class)){
        Set<Map<String, String>> info = mapperCassandra(row, "conseillers");
    }
}

private Set<Map<String, String>> mapperCassandra(Row row, String type) {
    return  row.getSet(type,    TypeTokens.mapOf(TypeToken.of(String.class), TypeToken.of(String
            .class)));

}
```